# LaTeXタイトルで複数著者がいて、数人が同じ所属の場合の書き方

Tags: latex

はじめまして。
LaTeXでタイトルと概要を出力する際、

```
\author{木下\thanks{京都大学}　\and ベーテ\thanks{東京大学} \and ガモフ\thanks{京都大学}}
```

としたら、
タイトルの下に「木下＊、ベーテ＋、ガモフ￥」のように現れ、脚注に「＊京都大学、+東京大学、￥京都大学」と現れます。
これをタイトルの下に「木下＊、ベーテ＋、ガモフ＊」、脚注に「＊京都大学、+東京大学」と現すにはどうしたらよいでしょうか。

Comment: タイトルや著者名の記述法は，LaTeX 本体で決められているというよりは文書クラス依存です．したがって，お使いの文書クラス (jsarticle, jlreq, etc.) を明示した方が正確な回答が得られると思います．

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。文書クラスはjsarticleを使っています。他も試してみます。

Answer (score 3):

LaTeX 文書クラスによっては（特に学会やジャーナル提供のものなど）複数人の所属組織を記述しやすくするコマンドがデフォルトで提供されている場合があるのですが，jsarticle クラスにはそのような機能はなさそうなので，外部パッケージを利用するのが早いと思います．

例えば authblk パッケージは，ちょうど「複数著者のうち，数人が同じ組織に所属する」ようなケースにもうまく対応できるようです．

```
\documentclass{jsarticle}
\usepackage{authblk}

% タイトル
\title{テスト文書}

% 著者名
\author[1]{国立太郎}
\author[2]{私立一郎}
\author[1]{国立次郎}

% 所属
\affil[1]{某国立大学}
\affil[2]{某私立大学}

% 日本語対応
\renewcommand\Authsep{\qquad}
\renewcommand\Authand{\qquad}
\renewcommand\Authands{\qquad}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

ただし，デフォルト設定だと「国立太郎, 私立一郎, and 国立次郎」のような表示になってしまい，日本語文書にはそぐわないので，

```
% 日本語対応
\renewcommand\Authsep{\qquad}
\renewcommand\Authand{\qquad}
\renewcommand\Authands{\qquad}
```

の箇所でセパレータ（区切り）を変更しています．ここのあたりは，適宜変更してお使いになればよろしいかと思います．

Answer (score 0):

同じ所属の著者が２人以上いる場合、２人目以降は\thanksを使用せず、\footnotemark[番号]で直接脚注番号を入力すれば可能だと思います。